# What is the difference alignment parent and child?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

What is the difference  `android:layout_alignParentRight` and  `android:layout_alignRight`?It doesnt make me any sense?

My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="320dip"
        android:background="@drawable/merhaba_bg_320_480dip">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="320dip"
              android:layout_height="480dip"  >



**<ImageView
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:layout_width="64dip"
        android:id="@+id/merhaba_btn_nedir"
        android:background="@drawable/merhaba_btn_nedir_64_30dip"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/bla">
</ImageView>**




    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_height="44dip"
            android:layout_width="320dip"
            android:background="@drawable/merhaba_header_320_44dip"
            **android:id="@+id/bla**">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="32dip"
            android:layout_width="121dip"
            android:background="@drawable/merhaba_logo_121_32dip"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true">
        </ImageView>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:layout_width="64dip"
            android:background="@drawable/merhaba_btn_nedir_64_30dip"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
        </ImageView>
    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
android:layout_alignParentRight
```

Accepts a boolean value, and if set to `true`, it'll make the right edge of this view match the right edge of the parent.

```
android:layout_alignRight
```

Accepts an id (reference to another view in the same view group), and makes the right edge of this view match the right edge of the given anchor view.

In other words: the first allows you to position a view relative to its parent, whereas the second positions a view relative to some other view (which should be a sibling view in the same parent). There are similar attributes for left, top and bottom.

Visualizing things usually helps a lot - just try some different variations of both and watch their results in Eclipse's layout editor.

Comment: Hi; thx for reply my question is which one is my parent view in here? My last view just working with android:layout_alignParentRight .so when i delete one of my background android:layout_alignRight is not still work? I am a bit confused .Can you help me please? I edit my question

Comment: Above attributes are only valid for `RelativeLayout`, which automatically means that the 'parent' view is a RelativeLayout. That should answer your first question. Regarding your second: I'm not sure what you mean - you're mixing both `android:layout_alignParentRight` and `android:layout_alignRight` in one sentence, but bear in mind that they are different things (as answered above). Perhaps it's easier if you try to explain what you're trying to accomplish in stead?

Comment: I want to align right in nedir button.I was thinking android:layout_alignRight is work but it was not.so you are saying that if i not use layout button can be align right. my expectation my title must be left and imageview must be right but it doestn work?

Comment: The ImageView annotated by `**` is not inside a RelativeLayout, but inside a `LinearLayout`. Hence `android:layout_alignRight="@id/bla"` will have no effect. I'm not sure what your 'title' is, but if you want to align the ImageView to the right of it, use `android:layout_toRightOf="<id>"`. If you want to align the right edges (useful for positioning elements above/below each other), then use `android:layout_alignRight="<id>"`. Do make sure these elements are within (the same) RelativeLayout.

Comment: ah now i get it.Thx for that=)